# Retornar checkbox preenchido

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho um script que me retorna a partir do ID, o nome e o checkbox Inativo, porém mesmo quando alguém se marcou como inativo minha função não retorna este campo preenchido.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("input[name='id']").blur(function(){
                    var $nome = $("input[name='nome']");
                    var $inativo = $("input:checkbox[name='inativo']:checked");

                    $.getJSON('function_pes.php',{ 
                            id: $( this ).val() 
                    },function( json ){
                            $nome.val( json.nome );
                            $inativo.val( json.inativo );

                    });
            });
    });
</script>
<!-- Fim do script de preenchimento automático dos campos a partir do campo ID -->

               <form action="salvar_pessoa.php" method="post"><!-- Inicio Form -->
                    <div class="col-lg-2"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
                        <label for="ex1">ID:</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="13"  name="id">
        </div><!-- Fim Input ID -->

        <div class="col-lg-5"><!-- Inicio Input Nome -->
                        <label for="ex1">Nome:</label>
                        <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="50"  name="nome">
        </div><!-- Fim Input Nome -->

        <div class="col-lg-10"><!-- Inicio checkbox Registro Inativo-->
                        <div class="checkbox" style="margin-top:30px;">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="inativo" value="true" style="outline:none;">Registro Inativo
                            </label>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver já o problema, então vou postar aqui caso alguém também passe por isso, basta alterar o json para receber somente valores que realmente forão marcados / checkados. E assim retorno sempre somente os checkbox que estão marcados no banco de dados com valor booleano 1

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("input[name='id']").blur(function(){
                var $nome = $("input[name='nome']");
                var $inativo = $("input:checkbox[name='inativo']:checked");

                $.getJSON('function_pes.php',{ 
                        id: $( this ).val() 
                },function( json ){
                        $nome.val( json.nome );
                        $inativo.prop('checked', !!+json.inativo );
                });
        });
});
```

```
           <form action="salvar_pessoa.php" method="post"><!-- Inicio Form -->
                <div class="col-lg-2"><!-- Inicio Input ID -->
                    <label for="ex1">ID:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="13"  name="id">
    </div><!-- Fim Input ID -->

    <div class="col-lg-5"><!-- Inicio Input Nome -->
                    <label for="ex1">Nome:</label>
                    <input type="text" required class="form-control" maxlength="50"  name="nome">
    </div><!-- Fim Input Nome -->

    <div class="col-lg-10"><!-- Inicio checkbox Registro Inativo-->
                    <div class="checkbox" style="margin-top:30px;">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="inativo" value="true" style="outline:none;">Registro Inativo
                        </label>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para alterar o estado de um checkbox, use `$inativo.prop('checked', json.inativo);`.
O value de um checkbox não diz respeito ao seu estado, ele apenas indica o que será passado ao servidor caso esteja marcado.

Comment: agora retorna todos checkbox preenchidos mesmo se não tiver sido marcado ao fazer o cadastro

Comment: Verifique o seu json se não está sempre marcando `true` ou talvez o `false` pode estar codificado em string  
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean

Comment: já resolvi o problema, obrigado ficou desta forma o json => $inativo.prop('checked', !!+json.inativo); e desta forma consigo retornar todos os meu checkbox preenchidos e diferenciar dos quqe não estão preenchidos